# How can we implement live updates functionality in mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is something like lets take gmail as example, when you open gmail then your personal dashboard gets open up.Now whenever any new messages come it will be notified to you without the whole page getting loaded again.so similar fetaure we want to implement in our MVC application.

I hope, my point is clear..

Comment: Take a look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Comment: You can also write a simple AJAX library and some controller with caching to scale it well.

Comment: thanks @StephenMuecke i guess it should work.let me try for it..

Comment: Thanks @Devesh.Will try for it also..